# Returning value from callback to its parent

Tags: java, rest, gwt, asynccallback

I need to return value gained as a result of rest service call to its parent. Issue is I am calling rest service (using async callback class) so I need to "wait" for the result and then pass it to somewhere else. Please check out following snippet.

```
config.addC(AppController.LOCALE.getMod(),new StringC<SomeEntry>() {
public String getValue(SomeEntry object) {
            Rest.getSomething(AppController.getRest(),  object.getId(), idAccess, null, null,  new AsyncCallback<SomeStructureList>() {

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(final SomeStructureList result) {
                    return result.getSometing().getSomethingElse(); // i need to have access to variable result in the parent function getValue()
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
                    // fail...
                }
            });

            return getRes(); //TODO as well
        }
});
```

What is the propper way to do that? Thanks in advance.
EDIT: I added some more code to make it more clear.

Answer (score 4):

One way is to define an interface:

```
public interface GetValueCallback() {
    onSuccess(SomeStructureList result);
}
```

Then set a callback parameter to that getValue method implementing that interface:

```
public String getValue(SomeEntry object, GetValueCallback callback) {
    Rest.getSomething(AppController.getRest(),  object.getId(), idAccess, null, null,  new AsyncCallback<SomeStructureList>() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(final SomeStructureList result) {
            callback.onSuccess(result);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
            // fail...
        }
    });

    return getRes(); //TODO as well
}
```

Finally, perform the call by passing a callback and you'll receive the result as a parameter:

```
getValue(object, new Callback() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(SomeStructureList result) {
        // You can do whatever you need with the result here
    }
});
```

If you are interesed in other ways you could also have a look at RxJava.

Comment: Your code doesn't work for me, could you please double check it for some typos/mistakes? Thank you.

Comment: Well, you have updated the question, where is this StringC defined?

Answer (score 0):

Well it should go the other way around. You are used to call method like `getValue` and then do something with the result. Now you have to use `onSuccess` method to do what you want. If it is needed you can pass with as parameter in `getValue` callback function which can be executed inside `onSuccess` method.

Comment: I do not think so. As you can see I use parameter `object` in rest call.

Comment: My idea was exactly as @jeprubio wrote it. Maybe I didn't explain it correctly.